# How can i download a file from minio server URL

Tags: java, android, android-download-manager, minio

This is the [URL](https://stag-minio.shoppre.com/test/2022/1/0f9ee055-f321-4b69-9e0e-3672bf2ee3eb.pdf?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=VLJVI0W8O91GZ7UTP9M7%2F20220317%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220317T111707Z&X-Amz-Expires=86400&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=5d3f8a095ac5cae67a182e6c1c64ce0095f97432abe266cc2d37e24472534d55) I am getting from response which is minion encoded

Here I am trying to decode the URL which I got from the API response which is encoded by minio

```
        LoadingDialog.showLoadingDialog(getActivity(), "");
        Call<DownloadInvoiceModelResponse> call = TransactionRetrofitClient.getInstance3().getAppApi().downloadInvoice("Bearer " + sharedPrefManager.getBearerToken(), transactionId);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<DownloadInvoiceModelResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<DownloadInvoiceModelResponse> call, Response<DownloadInvoiceModelResponse> response) {
                if (response.code() == 200) {
                    if (response.body().getObject()!=null && !response.body().getObject().equals("")){
                        url = response.body().getObject();
`Trying to decode the URL i am getting from response`
                        try {
                            result = URLDecoder.decode(url, "UTF-8");
                            Log.d("Decoded URL", result);
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                            // not going to happen - value came from JDK's own StandardCharsets
                        }

                        tvDownloadInvoice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    LoadingDialog.cancelLoading();

                } else if (response.code() == 401) {
                    callRefreshTokenApi("download");
                } else {
                    LoadingDialog.cancelLoading();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), response.message(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<DownloadInvoiceModelResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                LoadingDialog.cancelLoading();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Here I am trying to download a file from decoded URL which is coming from the API response

```
private void downloadFile() {

    getActivity().registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));

    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(result));
    String title = URLUtil.guessFileName(result, null, null);
    request.setTitle(title);
    request.setDescription("Downloading file please wait....");
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, title);

    downloadManager = (DownloadManager) `enter code here`getActivity().getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    downloadManager.enqueue(request);

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Downloading Start", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```